# How to prevent ScheduledExecutorService from running multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation

I am using a `ScheduledExecutorService` on my Searching fragment where every 10 seconds I get a location. However, when I leave the fragment this will keep on running which is fine but if I re-enter the Searching fragment it will initiate a new task stacking up from the previous one and that will keep on stacking every time I exit and renter the fragment which is bad.

Is there a way to limit this to one task only?

`ScheduledExecutorService` inside `onCreateView`

```
     ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
        // This schedule a task to run every 10 seconds:
        scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            if(v.getContext() != null){
                try {
                    // code executes every 10 seconds.
                    searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
                    getLocation();
                    Log.d("TIMER", String.valueOf(scheduleTaskExecutor));

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Logs from entering twice the Searching fragment

`D/TIMER: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@c5fde06[Running, pool size = 5, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 7] D/lat: 37.4219983 D/long: -122.084 D/NOTICE: searching D/Found: 31 D/TIMER: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@13ab459[Running, pool size = 5, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 5] D/lat: 37.4219983 D/long: -122.084 D/NOTICE: searching D/Found: 31`

The `getLocation()` and `doSearch()` function

```
   private void getLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            AppActivity a = (AppActivity) getActivity();
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext()).requestLocationUpdates(Objects.requireNonNull(a).mLocationRequest, null);
            fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                        if (location != null) {
                            // Logic to handle location object
                            searchRequest.setLatitude(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                            searchRequest.setLongitude(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                            userLocation = location;
                            Log.d("lat", searchRequest.getLatitude());
                            Log.d("long", searchRequest.getLongitude());
                            doSearch();
                        } else {
                            Log.d("Location", "Location is null");
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        Log.d("ERROR", "Failed");
                        if (searchRequest != null && searchRequest.getTerm() != null) {
                            doSearch();
                        }
                    })
            ;
        } else {
            // You can directly ask for the permission.
            // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void doSearch() {
        View view = requireActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
```

Comment: So you basically want to cancel existing tasks when you create a new one? In that case you'd need to keep track of the futures that are returned when submitting the tasks and cancel those.

Comment: Correct, so if I re visit the fragment it should cancel the existing one and start a new task. tried using ```.shutdown();``` but didn't quite work

Comment: Don't shut down the executor but cancel the tasks. When you call `scheduleAtFixedRate(...)` you'll get back a `ScheduledFuture` which you'll need to keep around and once you no longer want to keep those tasks you just call `cancel()` on that future.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I got you right but

```
 ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: unfortunately no, every time i re visit the fragment its starts another task on top so it runs 2 and if i visit again it runs 3 and so on...

Comment: How is it possible that a single thread runs multiple tasks in parallel? If you narrow the thread pool to 1 you basically force it to run tasks one after another.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me was doing this

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
// This schedule a task to run every 10 seconds:
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    try {
        searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        getLocation();
        Log.d("TIMER", String.valueOf(scheduleTaskExecutor));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// Scheduling the tasks
for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i--) {
    try {
        searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        getLocation();
        Log.d("TIMER", String.valueOf(scheduleTaskExecutor));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    scheduleTaskExecutor.schedule(new Task(i), 10 - i,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

// so that it no longer accepts
// any new tasks
scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdown();
```